# Calculating the Standard Error and Standard Deviation of a Discrete Time Markov Chain

Tags: r, matrix, standard-error

I have a matrix of the counts of transitions from one state to another and I would like to calculate the Maximum Likelihood Estimates, standard errors and standard deviations. The "markovchain" package has an example but the data is a sequence. My data is obtained from a balanced panel dataset of 155 companies so the example code they provide doesn't work for me.

This is the example I followed:

```
 data(rain)
 rain$rain[1:10]

 [1] "6+"  "1-5" "1-5" "1-5" "1-5" "1-5" "1-5" "6+"  "6+"  "6+"

 #obtaining the empirical transition matrix
 createSequenceMatrix(stringchar = rain$rain)
      0 1-5  6+ 
0   362 126  60 
1-5 136  90  68 
6+   50  79 124

#fitting the DTMC by MLE
alofiMcFitMle <- markovchainFit(data = rain$rain, method = "mle", name = "Alofi")
alofiMcFitMle
$estimate
Alofi
A  3 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain defined by the following states:
 0, 1-5, 6+
 The transition matrix  (by rows)  is defined as follows:
            0       1-5        6+
0   0.6605839 0.2299270 0.1094891
1-5 0.4625850 0.3061224 0.2312925
6+  0.1976285 0.3122530 0.4901186
$standardError
             0        1-5         6+
0   0.03471952 0.02048353 0.01413498
1-5 0.03966634 0.03226814 0.02804834
6+  0.02794888 0.03513120 0.04401395
$confidenceInterval
$confidenceInterval$confidenceLevel
[1] 0.95
$confidenceInterval$lowerEndpointMatrix
            0       1-5         6+
0   0.6034754 0.1962346 0.08623909
1-5 0.3973397 0.2530461 0.18515711
6+  0.1516566 0.2544673 0.41772208
$confidenceInterval$upperEndpointMatrix
            0       1-5        6+
0   0.7176925 0.2636194 0.1327390
1-5 0.5278304 0.3591988 0.2774279
6+  0.2436003 0.3700387 0.5625151
$logLikelihood
[1] -1040.419
```

Because I already have a matrix of count data I can't use the above code. I just want to take my 6x6 matrix of transition counts and determine the maximum likelihood estimators, standard errors (confidence interval) and standard deviation. Does anyone have an example I could follow?

Comment: I don't see a proper statistical request. You are offering a single set of observations, apparently the ending state of some process, and are asking for `<something>` done by ML methods that relates to an unobserved process of transitions.

Comment: Yes. I would like to compute the MLEs for each transition of a 6x6 matrix, which is the count in each element of the matrix divided by the row sum. Once I have the MLEs, I would like to obtain the standard errors and standard deviations of the MLEs.

Comment: Still not clear what the MLE would be an estimate of. MLEs usually refer to a parameter of a statistical model. I don't see one yet capable of being calculated if you have not observed the full process.The best I could imagine being produced from a single 6x6 matrix are estimates of proportions and the se's might come from the multinomial distribution. However, there's no guarantee that these would be estimates of a transition matrix since we would not know the starting points and whether the process had achieved any sort of stability.

Comment: I should have mentioned the process I followed. My apologies. I'm assuming a first order Markov chain. I have 6 states representing the credit ratings of the 155 firms throughout my sample period. I count how many firms begin at state i and count how many of them transitioned to state j to make the matrix. The estimate is the proportion of firms that transitioned from state i to state j and the matrix is the probability distribution of the system.

Comment: I do not see why the observed counts from a Markov process with an undetermined starting state should necessarily provide sufficient information for the estimation of the process transition matrix.  You have not provided enough information in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could do this with the `markovchain` package, but you could write a function that would produce similar results.  The function below generates the estimates of the transition probabilities through MLE, but the standard errors, lower and upper confidence bounds via parametric bootstrap.  You can to either use the standard errors and estimates to make normal theory confidence intervals (`ci = "normal"`) or use the relevant quantiles of the parametric bootstrap distributions (`ci = "quantile"`).  The `parallel` flag identifies whether the levels of the matrix should be considered ordered or not.  If ordered, the model uses an ordered login to calculate probabilities.  If unordered (i.e., `parallel = FALSE`), then a multinomial login is used to calculate probabilities.

If I understand correctly, you're starting with something that looks like the output from `createSequenceMatrix(stringchar = rain$rain)`, without the underlying sequence of values that generated it. Here's how it would work.

1. Generate the data.

```r
library(markovchain)
#> Package:  markovchain
#> Version:  0.9.0
#> Date:     2022-07-01
#> BugReport: https://github.com/spedygiorgio/markovchain/issues
data(rain)
mat <-  createSequenceMatrix(stringchar = rain$rain)
```

2. Make the functions to estimate the models and print the results.

```r
mcmat_est <- function(mat, parallel = FALSE, ci = c("normal", "quantile"), conf_level=.95, R=2500){
  ci <- match.arg(ci)
  if(!is.null(rownames(mat))){
    vals <- rownames(mat)
  }else{
    vals <- 1:nrow(mat)
  }
  state_vals <- lapply(vals, \(i)data.frame(vals = rep(vals, mat[i, ])))
  if(parallel){
    state_vals <- lapply(state_vals, \(x){x$vals <- factor(x$vals, levels=vals, ordered=TRUE); x})
    mods <- lapply(state_vals, \(x)MASS::polr(vals ~ 1, data=x, Hess = TRUE))
    draws <- lapply(mods, \(m)cbind(-Inf, MASS::mvrnorm(R, m$zeta, vcov(m)), Inf))
    qs <- lapply(draws, \(d)plogis(d))
    probs<- lapply(qs, \(x)x[,-1] - x[,-ncol(x)])
    ests <- lapply(mods, \(m)plogis(c(-Inf, m$zeta, Inf)))
    ests <- lapply(ests, \(e)e[-1]-e[-length(e)])
  }else{
    state_vals <- lapply(state_vals, \(x){x$vals <- factor(x$vals, levels=vals); x})
    mods <- lapply(state_vals, \(x)nnet::multinom(vals ~ 1, data=x, Hess = TRUE, trace=FALSE))
    draws <- lapply(mods, \(m)MASS::mvrnorm(R, c(0, coef(m)), 
                                            cbind(0, rbind(0, vcov(m)))))
    probs <- lapply(draws, \(d)prop.table(exp(d), 1))
    ests <- lapply(mods, \(m)exp(c(0, coef(m))))
    ests <- lapply(ests, \(e)e/sum(e))
  }
  logLik <- sum(sapply(mods, logLik))
  nobs <- sum(sapply(mods, \(x)attr(logLik(x), "nobs")))
  df <- sum(sapply(mods, \(x)attr(logLik(x), "df")))
  attr(logLik, "nobs") <- nobs
  attr(logLik, "df") <- df
  class(logLik) <- "logLik"
  est <- do.call(rbind, ests)
  se <- do.call(rbind, lapply(probs, \(p)apply(p, 2, sd)))
  crit_z <- 1-(1-conf_level)/2
  if(ci == "normal"){
    lwr <- est - qnorm(crit_z)*se
    upr <- est + qnorm(crit_z)*se
  }else{
    lwr <- do.call(rbind, lapply(probs, \(p)apply(p, 2, quantile, 1-crit_z)))
    upr <- do.call(rbind, lapply(probs, \(p)apply(p, 2, quantile, crit_z)))
  }
  rownames(est) <- rownames(se) <- rownames(lwr) <- rownames(upr) <- rownames(mat)
  colnames(est) <- colnames(se) <- colnames(lwr) <- colnames(upr) <- colnames(mat)
  res <- list(estimate = est, se = se, lower=lwr, upper=upr, logLik=logLik)
  class(res) <- "mcest"
  res
}
print.mcest <- function(x, ..., digits=3){
  cat("\nEstimated Transition Probabilities\n")
  print(x$estimate, digits=digits)
  cat("\nStandard Errors of Transition Probabilities\n")
  print(x$se, digits=digits)
  cat("\nLower Confidence Bounds\n")
  print(x$lower, digits=digits)
  cat("\nUpper Confidence Bounds\n")
  print(x$upper, digits=digits)
  cat('\n')
  print(x$logLik)
}
```

3. Estimate the models using the function I generated:

```r
out <- mcmat_est(mat)  
out
#> 
#> Estimated Transition Probabilities
#>         0   1-5    6+
#> 0   0.661 0.230 0.109
#> 1-5 0.463 0.306 0.231
#> 6+  0.198 0.312 0.490
#> 
#> Standard Errors of Transition Probabilities
#>          0    1-5     6+
#> 0   0.0203 0.0181 0.0135
#> 1-5 0.0281 0.0269 0.0248
#> 6+  0.0245 0.0289 0.0309
#> 
#> Lower Confidence Bounds
#>         0   1-5    6+
#> 0   0.621 0.194 0.083
#> 1-5 0.407 0.253 0.183
#> 6+  0.150 0.256 0.430
#> 
#> Upper Confidence Bounds
#>         0   1-5    6+
#> 0   0.700 0.265 0.136
#> 1-5 0.518 0.359 0.280
#> 6+  0.246 0.369 0.551
#> 
#> 'log Lik.' -1040.419 (df=6)
```

4. Compare toe the `markovchainFit()` output.

```r
fit <- markovchainFit(data = rain$rain, method = "mle", name = "Alofi")
fit
#> $estimate
#> Alofi 
#>  A  3 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain defined by the following states: 
#>  0, 1-5, 6+ 
#>  The transition matrix  (by rows)  is defined as follows: 
#>             0       1-5        6+
#> 0   0.6605839 0.2299270 0.1094891
#> 1-5 0.4625850 0.3061224 0.2312925
#> 6+  0.1976285 0.3122530 0.4901186
#> 
#> 
#> $standardError
#>              0        1-5         6+
#> 0   0.03471952 0.02048353 0.01413498
#> 1-5 0.03966634 0.03226814 0.02804834
#> 6+  0.02794888 0.03513120 0.04401395
#> 
#> $confidenceLevel
#> [1] 0.95
#> 
#> $lowerEndpointMatrix
#>             0       1-5        6+
#> 0   0.5925349 0.1897800 0.0817850
#> 1-5 0.3848404 0.2428780 0.1763188
#> 6+  0.1428496 0.2433971 0.4038528
#> 
#> $upperEndpointMatrix
#>             0       1-5        6+
#> 0   0.7286330 0.2700740 0.1371931
#> 1-5 0.5403296 0.3693669 0.2862663
#> 6+  0.2524073 0.3811089 0.5763843
#> 
#> $logLikelihood
#> [1] -1040.419
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The log-likelihoods for the two models are the same, which provides some confidence that the underlying estimation process is similar.  The standard errors are different - the original function doesn't use a parametric bootstrap.  I'm not sure what they do since the function to estimate the model is written in C++ and I haven't investigated the source code.  If this difference is unacceptable, perhaps someone else will be able to get closer.

Comment: @ DaveArmstrong: thank you so much for your answer! I will have to read it more carefully and let you know if I have any questions!

Comment: On another note, I have been working on this question - can you please take a look at this and let me know if I have done this correctly? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806562/correctly-using-clustereval-in-r